# Special Monotone SAT problem: NP complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, satisfiability

Say we have the set $X=\{ x_1, x_2, \dots \}$ of variables. Then we consider the following problem: Is the formula 
$$\bigwedge_{(a,b,c) \in A}(a \vee b \vee c) \wedge \bigwedge_{(a,b,c) \in B}(\neg a \vee \neg b \vee \neg c)$$
for $A,B \subset X^3$ satisfiable.

This problem has been called *Montone-3-Sat* before and it is known to be NP-complete.

My question is: If we assume that $A=B$ has to hold, is the problem still NP-complete? I.e. we ask if we can color vertices in such a way that always specific three of them do not have the same color.

The results I have found on the internet confuse me a bit, because I believe the definitions of Monotone-Sat, Not-All-Equal-Sat are not always the same.  The definitions of NAE3SAT I've seen allow arbitrary 3-CNF-formulae as input, so this doesn't seem the same as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variant where $A=B$ is known as monotone [not-all-equal 3-satisfiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not-all-equal_3-satisfiability), i.e., Monotone NAE3SAT.  According to Wikipedia, it is NP-complete.  It is not the same problem as Monotone-3-SAT.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think my confusion stems from the fact that it seems to me that some allow people allow arbitrary 3-CNF-formulae as input for NAE3SAT and then ask if for every clause, we can find values different from TTT and FFF. As a simple example, for my problem $x_1\vee \neg x_2 \vee x_3$ is not a valid input. For some other people it would be a valid input and the formula would be NAE3-satisfiable for them by assigning e.g. $x_{1,2,3} = T$, because then we have TFT for our clause which is different from TTT and FFF.

Comment: @blablablup, you're right, I was confused.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! The definition of Monotone NAE3SAT for most people however seems to be the problem above with $B=\emptyset$. So they only allow non-negated literals. This would again be different from my problem. (see e.g. https://bit.ly/2UGjPQR)

Comment: Another source with both (monotone) NAE3SAT mentioned: http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.890/fall14/scribe/lec4.pdf

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, but NAE3SAT with the clause $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ seems equivalent to me to your problem with $A=B=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\}$.  So your problem with $A=B$ seems equivalent to Monotone NAE3SAT to me.  Your problem with $B=\emptyset$ seems to be equivalent to Monotone 3SAT, not Monotone NAE3SAT.  Am I missing something again?

Comment: In the latter notes I linked the input for NAE3SAT seems to be an arbitrary 3-CNF formula and we want to find a solution s.t. all clauses are not TTT/FFF. Then Monotone NAE3SAT seems to be the same but only clauses with positive literals are allowed. For Montone SAT we only allow all positive or all negative literals and check ordinary satisfiability. My problem is, that I cannot really find a proper detailed mathematical definition of these problems. What exactly is the input and what is the question we ask for each of the problems...

Comment: @blablablup, sure, that's identical what I wrote in my last comment.   Try working through the example in my previous comment?   If you have the formula $(x_1\lor x_2 \lor x_3)$ and want a solution where $x_1x_2x_3$ are not all TTT/FFF, that's equivalent to your problem with $A=B=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I believe, I got the difference of all the problems now!